# Balancer is down after stopping config servers

Tags: replication, mongodb

I had an urgent issue to solve in admin DB

I stopped all config servers, and made changes in the primary one.
After restarting all other servers - balancer working only on the server where I did changes, the other two have:

balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no

Also `rs.status()` returns:

```
configsvr> rs.status()
{
        "info" : "configsvr",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet",
        "code" : 76
}
```

Need some help to fix it
Should I restart all config servers with some options, or need to build replication from the beginning?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557352/errmsg-server-is-not-running-with-replset

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Hi, thanks for the answer

I checked that topic, but seems I had different issue

Results of ps -ef on all the servers are the same:

ps -ef | grep mongo
mongod    6328     1  3 Sep11 ?        03:02:29 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf

All the servers running exactly mongod with same options

Or the problem is still the same as on the topic you gave?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: balancer is running ONLY at config server replica sets PRIMARY, never on SECONDARY.

Second: (as) your error message says that, that node where you gave `rs.statatus()` command is not started in replica set mode, more like maintenance mode. i.e. started without --replSet or replication.replSetName config parameter and maybe also without "sharding.clusterRole: configsvr" parameter.

You can check what where starting parameters, by just reading mongod.log file. There is (at startup) list of parameters what that mongod used when it was started.